# Old version bootstrap modal remove class from body on going second modal from first modal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

Well, latest bootstrap versions don't have this problem. But, I am not able to change an existing website's library version. So, I am trying to fix the issue manually for my project. The issue is old for earlier 3.x versions of bootstrap. Open another modal from a modal remove the `.modal-open` from `body`. I have not found the solutions yet. What I have tried is adding the class again by targeting the ID of the second modal:

```
$(document)
    .on('shown.bs.modal', '#secondModal', function () { $('body').addClass('modal-open') })
    .on('hidden.bs.modal', '#secondModal', function () { $('body').removeClass('modal-open') });
```

Though this works, this is not the perfect solution. Because, at the time of closing First Modal, it removes `.modal-open` from body once and again it add the class with opening the second modal at the same time. But, the effect of removing and adding the class is visible clearly (as removing that class from body element causing the double scrolling issue) which I don't want. I want from going to second modal from first modal, `.modal-open` won't be removed. It will only be removed after closing second modal. How to do that without any touch in bootstrap.js?

[Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/learner73/y5a3n6ow/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More elegant way to resolve the problem without adding and removing class from body and the effect won't be visible at all is adding and removing the `overflow` which basically is the reason and cause of the scroll bar when switching from first modal to second modal.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#secondModal').on('show.bs.modal', function() {
    $('body').css('overflow-y', 'hidden');
  });
  $('#secondModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
    $('body').css('overflow-y', '');
  });
});
```

Note: first event change from `shown` to `show` when modal is about to show so scroll bar hidden effect won't be noticeable at all and second event should be `hidden` otherwise with `hide` you can see the second scroll-bar appear and disappear.

[Working Fiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/y5a3n6ow/1/)

Comment: Nice solution! Thanks.